# Outspoken badge not awarded since June?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

Today I noticed that [the Outspoken badge has not been awarded since June 15, 2014](//stackoverflow.com/help/badges/998/outspoken). That looks really weird because this is very unlikely.

Did nobody meet the requirements for the badge after that date, or is this a bug?

Comment: This looks very much like a bug.

Comment: 62 awarded from January-June, and 0 awarded from July-December?  Seems kinda unlikely to be entirely random...

Comment: @iCodez: if you were to put the awarding dates in buckets, you'll see that the drop after June is entirely unnatural.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Stack Overflow retrieves the information which users deserve the badge via an HTTP request from chat. And this request was made without a specific timeout value, which means it used our default of 3000 ms. And apparently in June we crossed the line where chat had little enough messages for this calculation to take less than three seconds (lots of graph theory going on there; see the detailed [description of the Outspoken badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#188731) if you're curious, and also [Hopcroft–Karp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm)).

And to add insult to injury, this failure wasn't logged to the exception log, just to the output of our task scheduler. This output gets written to a ton of plain-text files that nobody ever looks at, because for important things we have the [exception log](https://github.com/NickCraver/StackExchange.Exceptional) after all…

Anyway, I've increased the timeout and made sure to log these failures in the future, so after the next build, there'll be a huge chat badge award party of about 80 people. Thanks for noticing this.